# Red "X" in "Android Device Chooser" in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have created an Android 4.0 AVD. When I start the AVD and go to run my app, there is a red "X" next to the 4.0 AVD. When I choose that AVD, it does not install the app.

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I have `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>` , which I think should be fine for a 4.0 device (SKD 16 is 4.1)

Here's a screen shot of the Android Device Chooser
[image]

Comment: Can you paste the log output from the Console. Or if you try to use adb directly (from the platform-tools folder in the sdk), adb -e install <path to your apk> can you paste the output of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

1. Give your adb a breath by "**adb kill-server**" and "**adb start-server**" and see if it fixed
2. Let eclipse Run button, start your emulator instead of manually starting that
3. Recreate your avd with other versions of sdk and check if they work. If only version 4.0 doesn't work, I guess you must remove this version (4.0) sdk and install it again from scratch.

Comment: The kill-server / start-server seemed to do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome, I do recommend you, to try these commands before anything else if you face an error related to avd